# macOS - Dockerize MySQL service connection refused, crashes upon use

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Using `mysql(v8.0.21) image` with **mac** `docker-desktop (v4.2.0, Docker-Engine v20.10.10)`

As soon service up:

- entrypoints ready
- innoDB initialization done
- ready for connection

But as soon try to run the direct script(query) it crashes, refused to connect (also from phpmyadmin) and restarted again.

1. [terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78R9b.png)
2. [connection refused for phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok4YK.png)

*In the logs we are able to see an Error:*

> [ERROR] [MY-011947] [InnoDB] Cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory

*The error we are able to see into log is not an issue, as it is fixed and updated by InnoDB already, here is the reference below:*

> https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11840

---

**Note:** **docker-compose** file we are pretty much sure that, there is no error as same is working fine for windows as well ubuntu, but the issue is only for macOS.

Comment: This sounds like something you should post at the corresponding bug tracker

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't really an answer, but maybe it will save you trouble: If you can't get this solved, consider switching to a MariaDB container, which should act fine as a drop-in replacement for MySQL in most situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks **@NicoHaase** and **@Patrick** for going through the question and suggestions.

Found the reason for connection refused and crashing, posting answer so that it maybe helpful for others.

It was actually due to docker-desktop macOS client there was by default 2GB Memory was allocated as Resource, and for our scenario it was required more than that.

**We just allocate more memory according to our requirement and it was just started working perfectly fine.**

For resource allocation:

> - open docker-desktop preferences
> - resources > advanced
>   [image: docker-desktop resources allocation]